# What is wrong with my shell script?

Tags: scripts

The following program is giving error on line 7 and 9: the `while` loop does not seem to be working. It is a program to show all the prime and composite numbers from 3 to a desired given input.

```
echo prograam to find all the prime numbers from 3 to given number
echo enter the last number
read number
n=$number
i=3
m=3
    while [ $m -le $n ]
    do 
        while [ $i -le $m ]
        do  
        m=`expr $n % $i`
        i=`expr $i +1`
            if [ $m -eq 0 ]
            then
            echo $n is a prime number \n
            else
            echo $n is not a prime number \n
            fi
        done
    m=`expr $m +1`
    done
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-wrote the shell script for you:

```
echo "program to find all the prime numbers from 3 to given number"
echo "enter the last number"
read number
n=$number
i=2
m=2
is_prime=0
    while [ "$m" -lt "$n" ]
    do
        while [ "$i" -le "$m" ]
        do
            m=$(expr $n % $i)
            i=$(expr $i + 1)
            if [ "$m" -eq 0 ]
                then
                echo "$n is not a prime number"
                exit
            else
                is_prime=1
            fi
        done
    m=$(expr "$m" + 1)
    done
if [ "$is_prime" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "$n is a prime number"
fi
exit
```

Referred to the following for this:

- [Operators in bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)
- [How to use expr in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390805/how-to-use-expr-command-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 3):

I will not solve your problem, but I will show you where you are wrong. There are 2 kind of mistakes in your script:

1. <strike>`[ $m -le $n ]`</strike>. When you compare two integers in bash, you should use quotes as follow:

   ```
   [ "$m" -le "$n" ]
   ```

   or:

   ```
   (("$m" <= "$n"))
   ```

   More about: [Comparison Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).
2. <strike>`` i=`expr $i +1` ``</strike>. When you use `expr`, use spaces before and after operators. So, the right way is:

   ```
   i=`expr $i + 1`
   ```

   Others alternatives are:

   ```
   let i=$i+1
   ```

   or:

   ```
   i=$(($i+1))
   ```

   More about: [Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html).

Comment: With bash, using double brackets removes the need for quotes: `[[ $m -le $n ]]` is safe. Within double parentheses, the dollar is not necessary `(( m <= n ))`. You can do variable assignment in double parenthese: `(( i++ ))`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the syntax errors in your script Radu already pointed out, there are few logical error. I am giving you the refined code. It will **assert if a number is prime or not within the range**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "prograam to find all the prime numbers from 3 to given number"
echo "enter the last number: "
read number

m=3
while [ $m -le $number ]
do
    i=2
    flag=0
    while [ $i -lt $m ]
    do
    if [ `expr $m % $i` -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "$m is not a prime number"
        flag=1
        break               
    fi
    i=`expr $i + 1` 
    done
    if [ "$flag" = 0 ]; then
    echo "$m is a prime number"
    fi
   m=`expr $m + 1`
done
```

I have introduced a new variable `flag` to print out the numbers properly. save the script as `check_prime.sh` and give it execution permission.

**Output**

```bsh
$ ./check_prime.sh
prograam to find all the prime numbers from 3 to given number
enter the last number: 
12
3 is a prime number
4 is not a prime number
5 is a prime number
6 is not a prime number
7 is a prime number
8 is not a prime number
9 is not a prime number
10 is not a prime number
11 is a prime number
12 is not a prime number
```